# Duplicating material just creates a new name?

Tags: materials, error, duplicate

Using Blender v4.0 but I had the same problem in v3.6 on Apple Mac.

I am trying to duplicate a material but when I have the material selected and click on 'New material add material' all that happens is the name of the original material changes name. You can see in the image at the end of the material 026 denoting how many times I have tried to duplicate it.

I don't think I am doing this wrong? But am I?

[image]

Comment: if you click on this button it duplicates your material, you can select the original material if you click on the down arrow button next to the name

Answer (score 4):

You are indeed duplicating the material. The new material replaces the old one in the active slot. The old material still exists and is still used by other *users* (objects). What you probably want is to add a new slot, choose the same material as in the previous slot, and then duplicate it:

[image]